# How to select previous RECORD in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

USING VB 6.0

How to select previous row value?

Am Selecting a Date between fromdate and todate using date picker

Code

```
Dim stdate, endate as string

stdate = Fromdate
endate = todate
```

Example:

```
fromdate:  01-01-2009
todate: 01-06-2009
```

Data’s will display fromdate to todate.

I want to select previous date means previous row value.
How to select previous row value?

We cannot give

```
stdate = - fromdate 
endate =  - todate
```

It will display a data’s between 31-01-2008 to 31-05-2009

We cannot give

```
Stdate = <fromdate
endate = < todate
```

It will display a data’s before 01-01-2009 and also we cannot use > in between condition

```
Stdate = fromdate (Here how can I give “from previous row value of the fromdate”)
endate =  todate (here how can I give   “to previous row value of the todate”)
```

Example:

```
    id, date, name

    01, 02-01-2009, raja
    01, 04-01-2009, raja
    02, 04-01-2009, ravi

so on.....

01, 28-05-2009, raja
01, 31-05-2009, raja

so on...
```

am selecting a date stdate = 04-01-2009, endate= 31-05-2009

Output shoud display like this -

```
01, 02-01-2009, raja
01, 04-01-2009, raja
02, 04-01-2009, ravi

.......

01, 28-05-2009, raja
```

It should dipslay one record Before ssdate and endate.

How to select previous row value?

Need Help in VB 6 code.

Comment: Can you give an example on which date range you mean by "previous"?

Comment: @Fredrik: Mentioned the example, go through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not completely understand what you are doing, but if you have a recordset object that is sorted on date you need to need something like

```
If (recordset.BOF = False) Then
   recordset.MovePrevious
End If
```

If you are asking how to get a recordset that contains one record before the start date you are going to have to expand your query to try to include at least on record before the fromdate, find the first record with the fromdate, then use the MovePrevious method above.

If you are just asking how to get a date prior to a given date then use the DateAdd method.

example - the below code will subtract 1 day from 2/1/2009 and put 1/31/2009 into the valriable.

```
dtPreviousDate = DateAdd("D", CDate("02-01-2009"), -1)
```